# Variable Importance for Logistic regression with categorical data?

Tags: regression, references, inference, importance

If I run the logistic regression with X variables containing categorical data. (I do one-hot encoding on categorical data)
How do I evaluate the variable importance?
Is there any methods or literature on this?

Comment: some people like to use Lasso in situations like these. In R, the glmnet package is popular.

Answer (score 0):

[Azen and Traxel's](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/1076998609332754) dominance analysis approach for logit regression could incorporate dummy or indicator coded categorical variables.

Implementations for this method can be found for [SAS](http://people.uwm.edu/azen/damacros/), [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dominanceanalysis/index.html), and [Stata](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457629.html) to my knowledge.

The indicator codes for each variable should be grouped together as a set in the analysis.  That is, all the codes representing a single variable should always be included or excluded jointly.